# MySql stops running in combination with Laravel Queue, Supervisor, and FFMPEg

Tags: linux, mysql, php, ffmpeg

After setting up queue listener to process uploaded videos with FFMPEG, I've come back to the server several times to find that MySql has stopped running. I checked drive space and it's about 77% used (43G out of 60G).

Here's my code in case it's useful:

```
public function fire($job, $data)
{
$data = json_decode($data['transcoding_message'], true);
$output_directory = '/home/ubuntu/transcodes/';
$amazon_array = array();

$s3 = AWS::get('s3');


//execute main transcoding thread

$cmd = 'sudo ffmpeg -i ' . $data['temp_file_url'] . ' -y -vcodec libx264 -tune zerolatency -movflags faststart -crf 20 -profile:v main -level:v 3.1 -acodec libfdk_aac -b:a 256k ' . $output_directory. $data['temp_file_key'] . '_HQ.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -s ' . $sq_width . 'x' . $sq_height . ' -tune zerolatency -movflags faststart -crf 25 -profile:v main -level:v 3.1 -acodec libfdk_aac -b:a 256k ' . $output_directory. $data['temp_file_key'] . '_SQ.mp4 -ss ' . $seek_half . ' -f image2 -vf scale=iw/2:-1 -vframes 1 ' . $output_directory. $data['temp_file_key'] . '_thumb.jpg';

exec($cmd." 2>&1", $out, $ret);


if ($ret)
{

    Log::error($cmd);
    echo 'Processing error' . PHP_EOL;
    //there was a problem
    return;
}

else
{
    //setup file urls
echo 'about to move files';

$hq_url = $this->bucket_root . $data['user_id'] . '/' . $data['temp_file_key'] . '_HQ.mp4';
$sq_url = $this->bucket_root . $data['user_id'] . '/' . $data['temp_file_key'] . '_SQ.mp4';;
$thumb_url = $this->bucket_root . $data['user_id'] . '/' . $data['temp_file_key'] . '_thumb.jpg';

$amazon_array['video_hq_url'] = $data['temp_file_key'] . '_HQ.mp4';
$amazon_array['video_sq_url'] = $data['temp_file_key'] . '_SQ.mp4';
$amazon_array['video_thumb_url'] = $data['temp_file_key'] . '_thumb.jpg';

        //copy from temp to permanent

foreach ($amazon_array as $k => $f)
{
    $uploader = UploadBuilder::newInstance()
        ->setClient($s3)
        ->setSource($output_directory.$f)
        ->setBucket($this->bucket)
        ->setKey('users/' . $data['user_id'] . '/' . $f)
        ->setConcurrency(10)
        ->setOption('ACL', 'public-read')
        ->build();

    $uploader->getEventDispatcher()->addListener(
        'multipart_upload.after_part_upload',
        function($event) use ($f) {
            // Do whatever you want
        }
    );

    try {
        $uploader->upload();
        echo "{$k} => Upload complete.\n" . PHP_EOL;

        DB::table('items')->where('id', $data['item_id'])->update(array($k => $this->bucket_root. $data['user_id'] . '/' .$f, 'deleted_at' => NULL));
        //delete local

        unlink($output_directory.$f);

        unset($uploader);
    } catch (MultipartUploadException $e) {
        $uploader->abort();
        echo "{$k} => Upload failed.\n" . PHP_EOL;
        continue;
    }
}

    //write to database

        DB::table('archives_items')->where('id', $data['archive_item_id'])->update(array('deleted_at' => NULL));
        DB::connection('mysql3')->table('video_processing')->where('id', $data['id'])->update(array('finished_processing' => 1));

    //delete files

    //delete s3
    $s3->deleteObject(
        array(
            'Bucket' => $this->temp_bucket,
            'Key' => $data['file_name']
        )
    );
    echo $data['temp_file_url'] . '=>' . " deleted from temp bucket.\n" . PHP_EOL;
    DB::connection('mysql3')->table('video_processing')->where('id', $data['id'])->update(array('deleted_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()));

}
    $job->delete();

    // end of processing uploaded video
    }


else
{
    return;
}
```

Any ideas as to why MySql would die like that?

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket     '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
```

I want to mention that the php artisan queue:listen command is being triggered via Supervisor and that I have 4 running concurrent processes.

Error log:

```
140613  5:37:52 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140613  5:37:52 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140613  5:37:52 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140613  5:37:52 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140613  5:37:52 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
140613  5:37:52 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
140613  5:37:52 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140613  5:37:52 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
140613  5:37:52  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
140613  5:37:53  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140613  5:37:54 InnoDB: 5.5.37 started; log sequence number 2922980986
140613  5:37:54 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
140613  5:37:54 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
140613  5:37:54 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
140613  5:37:55 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
140613  5:37:55 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
140613  5:38:10 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140613  5:38:10 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140613  5:38:10 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140613  5:38:10 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140613  5:38:10 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
140613  5:38:10 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
140613  5:38:10 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140613  5:38:10 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
140613  5:38:10 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140613  5:38:10 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140613  5:38:10 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140613  5:38:10 [ERROR] Aborting
140613  5:38:10 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: Why did MySQL stop running? Check its logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
>
> 140613  5:38:10 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool

Your system ran out of memory error 12 is the kernel signaling ENOMEM.

Comment: Since the command php artisan queue:work --queue=https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/587107866605/archive-cloud-processing --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=3 --tries=0 --env=local 
was executed, would this queue process failing bring down MySql with it?

Comment: It looks like your system ran out of memory is all I know.